# Error while indexing data from this.setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, setstate, giphy

I am creating a GIF search web app with the GIPHY API and react.

After I fetch the data from the API, I can index the data `console.log(json.data[0])`

```
.then((json) => {
      console.log(json.data[0]);
      this.setState({ myGif: json });
});
```

But when I set my state to the JSON file and I try to index the data `console.log(this.state.myGif.data[0])` I get an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property “0” from undefined

```
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.myGif.data[0]);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I would really appreciate getting a response

**Below is the full code of the component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            myGif: {},
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const api_key = 'rYJ5AxF8DXFqeX8ub81fbuje3J12lrh6';
        fetch(
            `http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=${api_key}&limit=3`
        )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json.data[0]);
                this.setState({ myGif: json });     
            });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.myGif.data[0]);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```

Comment: Can you please put your response json here, that will give more clarity

Comment: [link](https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=rYJ5AxF8DXFqeX8ub81fbuje3J12lrh6&limit=3) the data[0] in this link :)

Comment: @Asutosh Thank you for your response it really helped me and I understood better, but why did you deleted the post?

Comment: You are welcome, I have added it back, you may upvote and mark it as answer if you find it helpful

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `console.log` data like:

```
console.log(
      this.state.myGif.data
        ? this.state.myGif.data[0]
        : "data is not downloaded yet"
    );
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped me and made me understand better :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because when the first time the component is rendered, this.state.myGif.data does not exist, because the initial state of the myGif is just empty.
You should check if the data is loaded ...

```
console.log(this.state.myGif.data ? this.state.myGif.data[0] : "Loading •••");
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped me and made me understand better :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `json()`.

```
componentDidMount() {
        const api_key = 'rYJ5AxF8DXFqeX8ub81fbuje3J12lrh6';
        fetch(
            `http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=${api_key}&limit=3`
        )
            .then(response => {
                const data = response.data
                this.setState(data);     
            });
    }
```

Then in your render function you can `console.log(this.state)` to see your entire state. It's an array of objects so you'll need to map it out if you want to display all of them. You can map like this :

`this.state.data.map((item,i) => <li key={i}>Test</li>)`

Since `data` in your state may be `undefined` on the first render. You'll want to set a default value of `[]` for `this.state.data`

If you want to display the first one you can say `this.state && this.state[0].type`

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetch` and `setState` calls are both asynchronous. While it is fetching your `render` will already be called.

One way to fix this is to check for the current state e.g.

```
 render() {
        this.state.myGif && console.log(this.state.myGif.data[0]);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            myGif: {data:["Image is getting Loaded"]},
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const api_key = 'rYJ5AxF8DXFqeX8ub81fbuje3J12lrh6';
        fetch(
            `http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=ryan+gosling&api_key=${api_key}&limit=3`
        )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json.data[0]);
                this.setState({ myGif: json });     
            });
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.myGif.data[0]);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is </h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```